# How to use Font-your-face fonts with CKEditor?

Tags: 7, wysiwyg, theming

I am using some Google fonts via the [Font-your-face module](https://www.drupal.org/project/fontyourface) on my D7 website as well as [CKEditor](https://www.drupal.org/project/ckeditor) for content editing. To achieve full wysiwyg effect I would like to display the text in editor with these Google fonts. However I can't find the way to to this.

Should I give a try to the appropriate [CKEditor plugin](http://ckeditor.com/addon/ckeditor-gwf-plugin) or is there a way to solve this on Drupal level? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a long awaited and unanswered issue - https://www.drupal.org/node/1234030 - however I have found a page that describes how you can manually updated your CKEditor fonts list.

http://www.zyxware.com/articles/3692/drupal-how-to-add-fonts-in-ck-editor

I think this seems a bit too much, you would think that there would be a better system in place to support more fonts dynamically. There are apparently some hooks with the WYSIWYG module and Font Your Face - however as far as my knowledge goes CKEditor works better on it's own than as a part of WYSIWYG.